# Laravel Vue Inertia JS Flash Messages shows only once when in the same page and message redirect

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

Layout:

```
 <div v-if="$page.props.flash.message">
             <Notification :message="$page.props.flash.message" />
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
return back()->with('message', 'User Has Been Updated');
```

Notification Components:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'


defineProps({
  message: String
});


const showNotification = ref(false);

onMounted(() => {
  showNotification.value = true;
  setTimeout(() => showNotification.value = false, 2000);
});

</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="message && showNotification" class="flex items-center relative w-full p-4 mb-4 text-base leading-5 text-white bg-green-500 rounded-lg opacity-100 font-regular" role="alert">
    <svg class="flex-shrink-0 inline w-4 h-4 me-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path d="M10 .5a9.5 9.5 0 1 0 9.5 9.5A9.51 9.51 0 0 0 10 .5ZM9.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3ZM12 15H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h1v-3H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v4h1a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Z"/>
    </svg>
    <span class="sr-only">Info</span>
    <div>
      <span class="font-medium capitalize">{{ message }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

HandleInertiaRequests:

```
 'flash' => [
                'message' => fn () => $request->session()->get('message')
            ],
```

I want to display flash message everytime when request sent. But it show only once when same flash message